# URLDecode in Java for named list

Tags: java, list, jakarta-ee, collections

I need to Decode(URLDecode.decode) each and every object from a named list. I tried with itreating through the named list

```
 for (NamedList nlst : allLists) {
  try {
Namedlist temp =(NamedList) UrlDecode.decode(nlst.toString(),"UTF-8");
}
```

But it wont allow me to cast into a named list.

Please let me know how to acheive this.

Comment: I guess you mean [URLDecoder.decode(...)][1] ... 

No you cannot do what you taht, the method `decode` returns `String` and you are trying to cast it to `Namedlist` this is not possible you'll a [ClassCastException][2]


  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29
  [2]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html

Comment: Ok, Can i acheive the same in some other way?

Comment: what are you exactly trying to do ? do you have some String-data in `NamedList` witch you want to decode and store it back ? can you post more code and help us understand your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast a String to custom defined class. Think about this way  what you are going to do if you want to cast an Integer instance to a String, you will probably use static factory method valueOf() to **convert** Integer to a String rather than casting it.

So a workaround here is to provide your own static factory method in something like XXXUtil.java

```
public static NamedList valueOf(String s){
//TODO convert string to namedlist
}
```